# How to create UITableView Cell with avatar and text using Auto Layout in iOS with IB?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've tried `Label.width = width` constraint and get this:
[image]

But I want to get something like this:
[image]

So, the size of the label width equals the size of the table cell minus avatar width and paddings. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please decrease size of your images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve required effect you can add following constraints: 
[image]

Cell prototype: 
[image]

Label constraints:

[image]

After applying all constraints select cell's label and press <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to update label's frame

Comment: It just makes text centred in a cell. But i want it to place to the right of the image. It doesn't work

Comment: @SemyonTikhonenko make sure that left constraint is "Leading Space to: Image View" and not to content view

Comment: You'll probably want to take out the "magic numbers" in the constraints. Instead of `Trailing Space to: Superview Equals 8`, make change it to `Standard Value`. Same with `Top Space` and `Leading Space`

Comment: How to specify from what view leading space will be calculated?

Comment: @SemyonTikhonenko press control and drag from label to image. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/add_constraints-control_drag.html